Tap Widget outside Stack in Flutter
There is currently a known Flutter limitation that makes widgets overflowing beyond Stack to not receive gesture events.
However, there is a hack that seems to work by extending the Stack class.
Here is my updated implementation of the hack.
class StackTappableOutside extends Stack {
  const StackTappableOutside({
    super.key,
    super.alignment,
    super.textDirection,
    super.fit,
    super.clipBehavior,
    super.children,
  });

  @override
  RenderStack createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderStackTappableOutside(
      alignment: alignment,
      textDirection: textDirection ?? Directionality.of(context),
      fit: fit,
      clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
    );
  }
}

class RenderStackTappableOutside extends RenderStack {
  RenderStackTappableOutside({
    super.alignment,
    super.textDirection,
    super.fit,
    super.clipBehavior,
    super.children,
  });

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    if (hitTestChildren(result, position: position) || hitTestSelf(position)) {
      result.add(BoxHitTestEntry(this, position));
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

I tested it and it works well in Column and Row
(Reproducible, just copy and paste)
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class StackTappableOutside extends Stack {
  const StackTappableOutside({
    super.key,
    super.alignment,
    super.textDirection,
    super.fit,
    super.clipBehavior,
    super.children,
  });

  @override
  RenderStack createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderStackTappableOutside(
      alignment: alignment,
      textDirection: textDirection ?? Directionality.of(context),
      fit: fit,
      clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
    );
  }
}

class RenderStackTappableOutside extends RenderStack {
  RenderStackTappableOutside({
    super.alignment,
    super.textDirection,
    super.fit,
    super.clipBehavior,
    super.children,
  });

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    if (hitTestChildren(result, position: position) || hitTestSelf(position)) {
      result.add(BoxHitTestEntry(this, position));
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

class TapOutsideStackDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const TapOutsideStackDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<TapOutsideStackDemo> createState() => _TapOutsideStackDemoState();
}

class _TapOutsideStackDemoState extends State<TapOutsideStackDemo> {
  List<int> items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tap Outside Stack Demo'),
      ),
      body: _body(),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(int index, int element) {
    final showAddButton = index > 0;
    return StackTappableOutside(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Todo List Item $element'),
            subtitle: Text('Add a new item after'),
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow),
          ),
        ),
        if (showAddButton)
          Positioned(
            top: -24,
            right: 8,
            child: Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('add after');
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _body() {
    return Column(
      children: items.mapIndexed(_itemBuilder).toList(),
    );
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final element = items[index];
        return _itemBuilder(index, element);
      },
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: TapOutsideStackDemo(),
  ));
}


With the above code, when you tap the green button from anywhere, it prints:
add after
add after
add after

However, I have a requirement to make it a ListView instead of Column. So I changed  from
  Widget _body() {
    return Column(
      children: items.mapIndexed(_itemBuilder).toList(),
    );
  }

to:
  Widget _body() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final element = items[index];
        return _itemBuilder(index, element);
      },
    );
  }

Suddenly, only half of the green button works. Only the bottom part works.
I also noticed that if we wrap the List Item with GestureDetector, the hack stops working too, even with the simple Column that worked earlier.

Can someone explain why it does not work on ListView ?

Is there any way I can force this to work on ListView and GestureDetector ?
I need to use ListView imperatively because I need to implement ReorderableListView.builder afterward.



It seems pretty weird that there seems to be no easy out of the box way to do this. But I found a nice pub package which seems to do the job for me: https://pub.dev/packages/defer_pointer
For your example it worked by wrapping the whole ListView.builder inside the  DeferredPointerHandler and wrapping the IconButton inside DeferPointer.
Here is your modified code sample:
class _TapOutsideStackDemoState extends State<TapOutsideStackDemo> {
  List<int> items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tap Outside Stack Demo'),
      ),
      body: _body(),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(int index, int element) {
    final showAddButton = index > 0;
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Todo List Item $element'),
            subtitle: Text('Add a new item after'),
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow),
          ),
        ),
        if (showAddButton)
          Positioned(
            top: -24,
            right: 8,
            child: Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: DeferPointer(
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('add before $element');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _body() {
    // return Column(
    //   children: items.mapIndexed(_itemBuilder).toList(),
    // );
    return DeferredPointerHandler(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        hitTestBehavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final element = items[index];
          return _itemBuilder(index, element);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Also note that this no longer requires the StackTappableOutside workaround.
